# how to pass Nodejs jade page in template url of ui.router of angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Hello I am trying to use NodeJS and angularJS both for my app.I want to create a single page application for that I need to use angularJS.

But I am unable to proceed.Didn't find any solution for How to use Jade files with ui.router

Answer (score 1):

I found answer ...

```
app.get("/login", function(req, res, next){
res.render("modules/login/index.jade");
});
```

Need to render the page so that it get compiled before passing to ui.router template url and under template url we just provide

```
templateurl:"/login"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code to how to configure UI Routing in Angular

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

sampleApp .config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/addOrder', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/add-order.html',
        controller: 'AddOrderController'
      }).
      when('/showOrders', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/show-orders.html',
        controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/addOrder'
      });
  }]);
```

Now you have to write server code to mapping with this routeing by node js

hope you know  how to write server side controller in the back-end with node js.
If you have any experience in WebAPI in .Net it's just like that

Please go through below link to more details on UI.Routing with Angular js

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/

Comment: I know how to use ui.router of angularjs, but i am not able to use jade files inspite of html files